# Barcode Printer taking 8 seconds to print next job

Tags: printing

I am using TSC TA210 barcode printer. It accepts job prints, everything is ok but when i submit 10 jobs at a time then it takes 8 second to complete single job (taking total time 10jobs * 8 sec per job = 80 sec to complete 10 jobs)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this from? Questions: (1) What does the following command give back: *`lpstat -v`* ?   (2) Which version of CUPS? (Please add this info to your OP...)

Comment: (1) Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: (2) CUPS 1.7 and 2.x